# Icon Dependent on Boolean not Changing when Boolean Value Changes (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, icons

I'm trying to make a Flutter screen that changes the icon (from unchecked to checked) when the ListTile is tapped. I've continued on from the first Flutter app tutorial, https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab which has something very similar that functions.

However, when I tap my ListTile the boolean changes values (as evidenced by my print() statement), but the icon stays the same, despite using setState(). I'm brand new to Flutter, could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: It looks like I needed to wrap after builder: in a StatefulBuilder... but now the question is how to address each check box individually, instead of all at once?

Comment: provide ready to run code

Comment: you should put your var checked = false outside your build

Comment: I think checked should be inside: moving it outside makes the bool apply to all 4 checkboxes, instead of each checkbox having its own. The icons still didn't update after doing so, either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a widget from a List<Widget> in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60939052/updating-a-widget-from-a-listwidget-in-flutter)

Comment: give unique bool name to each check box like bool checked, checked1, checked2... = false;